# How can I connect Android Studio with a local server database SQL Server 2008?

Tags: java, php, sql-server-2008, android-studio

I have a Microsoft SQL Server 2008 database on my local server and I want to create an Android application to send and receive data from this database.

Do I have to upload my database to the cloud first? Where should I start?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Database Access in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3391395/6521116)

Comment: Do you expect the android application to connect to the local db directly without any web services? and also do you understand that even if that becomes possible, you won't be able to access the db outside the local network?

Comment: Can you recommend a web service?

Comment: If you want to write the web service, then it depends on your choice what stack you are comfortable with and on which you can deploy. Being a Java developer, I generally use Tomcat + JAX-RS + DB kind of stack(this is not the complete stack its just an idea) to write web services. By your question, it seems that you might not be having knowledge of writing the same. Please refer this http://www.mkyong.com/tutorials/jax-ws-tutorials/

Answer (score 0):

If you want to test your android application with localserver or local database you'll need to have an emulator device. (You can use Android Studio's provided default emulator, or you can also install `Genymotion`  that is way better than default emulator of Android studio in terms of speed, performance etc). 
If you wan to test the application on real device then you have to upload your php files and databases to a live server.